# Does anything carry over from tales of berseria's free steam demo to a potential purchase?

Tags: steam, tales-of-berseria

Title says it all for the most part, if I play the free demo on steam, will anything carry over if I enjoy it and decide to buy the full game?

Comment: I do imagine that the save data from the demo would be accessible in the full game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't look like anything carries over, the demo has 2 stand-alone modules.